# Error on using google_distance with mutate

Tags: r, google-distancematrix-api, googleway

I'm trying to calculate the driving distance between two coordinate locations.  Here's my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(googleway)

distances %>%
  mutate(distance = google_distance(origins = origin, destinations = destination, key = 'API KEY'))
```

Here's my dataset - https://pastebin.com/d6Z6b2K5

I get this error:

```
Error in mutate():
! Problem while computing distance = google_distance(...).
✖ distance must be size 294 or 1, not 5.
```

I'd really appreciate some help with this!

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of `dput(head(distances))` please?

Comment: @SymbolixAU someone on DIscord suggested this modification to my code 

`mutate(distance = purrr::map2(origin, destination, ~ google_distance(.x, .y, key = 'API KEY')))`

Comment: If that works you should add it as an answer :)

Comment: @SymbolixAU just did!  Thanks a ton!  THis is my first time using StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution that worked for me

```
mutate(distance = purrr::map2(origin, destination, ~ google_distance(.x, .y, key = 'API KEY')))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).